# How to prevent a project from being generated?

Tags: premake

In a premake5.lua file describing a project, how can I tell it should not be generated under certain conditions (system, architecture...)?

Answer (score 0):

if you pass the conditions as command lines params 
it should be as easy as

```
if _options["cond"] == "value" then
```

project "Name"
...
end

Comment: I thought about this, however it means I have to wrap the whole project declaration inside an if block. I was hoping for some premake command to do this, like filters but for all the project, just one line to write would be perfect.

Comment: Premake currently doesn't support filtering of "containers" like solutions and projects by filters, but it isn't a bad idea. Would be good to [open an issue for it](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues), and link it back to this SO topic so it can be updated if they add the feature.